# PostgreSQL 9.1 streaming replication restore_command: special meaning of exit code 255?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1.3 streaming replication setup on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS (primary and standby). Replication is initialized with a streamed base backup ([`pg_basebackup`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby.html)). The [`restore_command`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/archive-recovery-settings.html#RESTORE-COMMAND) script tries to fetch the required WAL archives from a remote archive location with `rsync`.

Everything works like described in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby.html) when the restore_command script fails with an exit code <> 255:

> At startup, the standby begins by restoring all WAL available in the archive location, calling restore_command. Once it reaches the end of WAL available there and restore_command fails, it tries to restore any WAL available in the pg_xlog directory. If that fails, and streaming replication has been configured, the standby tries to connect to the primary server and start streaming WAL from the last valid record found in archive or pg_xlog. If that fails or streaming replication is not configured, or if the connection is later disconnected, the standby goes back to step 1 and tries to restore the file from the archive again. This loop of retries from the archive, pg_xlog, and via streaming replication goes on until the server is stopped or failover is triggered by a trigger file.

But when the restore_command script fails with exit code 255 (because the exit code from a failed rsync call is returned by the script) the server process dies with the following error:

```
2012-05-09 23:21:30 CEST - @  LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at     2012-05-09 23:21:25 CEST
2012-05-09 23:21:30 CEST - @  LOG:  entering standby mode
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [Receiver=3.0.7]
2012-05-09 23:21:30 CEST - @  FATAL:  could not restore file "00000001000000000000003D" from archive: return code 65280
2012-05-09 23:21:30 CEST - @  LOG:  startup process (PID 8184) exited with exit code 1
2012-05-09 23:21:30 CEST - @  LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

So my question is now: Is this a bug or is there a special meaning of exit code 255 which is missing in the otherwise excellent documentation or am I missing something else here?

Comment: I'm not making this an answer right now, because I don't have time to check the source code to confirm until later or tomorrow, but my recollection is that when applying WAL files during recovery, a non-zero exit code less than 255 means "failed but keep trying", while 255 (or higher) means "failed badly; give up". You may need to tweak your script to return a lesser exit code for the rsync failure.

Comment: @kgrittn: Thanks, I was thinking of something like this but I couldn't find any documentation concerning the special meaning of exit code 255 and I don't know where to look for it in the source code.

Comment: Er, it took a while, but this surfaced again as a question I had to deal with, and my comment here was referenced, so I looked it up and posted an answer with details.  I'll see about getting something into the docs this time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the primary server, you have `WAL` files sitting in the `pg_xlog/` directory. While `WAL` files are there, PostgreSQL is able to deliver them to the standby should they be requested.

Typically, you also have local archived `WAL` location, when files are moved there by PostgreSQL, they no longer can be delivered to the standby on-line and standby is expecting them to come from the archived `WAL` location via `restore_command`.

If you have different locations for archived `WAL`s setup on primary and on standby servers, then there's no way for a while to reach standby and you have a gap.

In your case this might mean, that:

- `00000001000000000000003D` had been archived by the primary PostgreSQL;
- standby's `restore_command` doesn't see it from the configured source location.

You might consider manually copying missing WAL files from primary to the standby using `scp` or `rsync`. It is also might be necessary to review your `WAL` locations and make sure both servers look in the same direction.

---

**EDIT:**
`grep`-ing for `restore_command` in sources, only `access/transam/xlog.c` references it. In function `RestoreArchivedFile` almost at the end (round line 3115 for 9.1.3 sources), there's a check whether `restore_command` had exited normally or had it received a signal.

In first case, message is classified as `DEBUG2`. In case `restore_command` received a signal other then `SIGTERM` (and wasn't able to handle it properly I guess), a `FATAL` error will be reported. This is true for all codes greater then 125.

I will not be able to tell you why though.
I recommend asking on the [hackers list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I was asking. I know why restore_command fails and how I can fix it, that's not the point. As a matter of fact restore_command _must_ fail at some point. My question is: why does an exit code > 0 but <> 255 have a different effect than exit code 255. With exit code 255 the standby server process dies while it should continue the _restore loop_ like it does with exit code 1 or 17.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the source code location. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an rsync problem I encountered temporarily using NFS (with rpcbind/rstatd on port 837):

```
$ rsync -avz /var/backup/* backup@storage:/data/backups
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

This fixed it for me:

```
service rpcbind stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue creating a hot standby (postgres 9.5). Streaming was working (I seeded the standby via pg_basebackup using the same credentials as would later be used in the standby's recovery.conf).

After taking the basebackup, I setup the following recovery.conf:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=ip.of.master port=5432 user=pgstandby password=password'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
restore_command = 'sftp -q user@ip.of.wal.archive.host:data/master_wal_archive/%f "%p"'
trigger_file = '/srv/pgsql/9.5/data/trigger'
```

Starting the server would yield:

```
2016-03-08 12:34:58.981 UTC  (/)LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2016-03-08 12:26:10 UTC
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
2016-03-08 12:34:59.525 UTC  (/)FATAL:  could not restore file "00000002.history" from archive: child process exited with exit code 255
2016-03-08 12:34:59.526 UTC  (/)LOG:  startup process (PID 26636) exited with exit code 1
2016-03-08 12:34:59.526 UTC  (/)LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

If I removed the restore_command line from recovey.conf, the standby started up fine and began streaming WALs from the master.

I eventually traced the problem down to not having added the standby postgres user's public key to the authorized_hosts file of the WAL archive host. I'd also forgotten to add the WAL archive host's server fingerprint to the known_hosts file of the standby postgres user.

These two mistakes were (I assume) causing the sftp restore_command to exit with code 255. As tscho says, the Postgres docs suggest that if the restore_command exits with ANY non-zero value, Postgres will simply move on to trying to stream from the master rather than refusing to start. In reality this doesn't seem to be the case if the exit code is higher than a certain number (maybe 125, as vyegorov's source code grepping suggests?).

Once I fixed the two SSH issues, the standby started fine with the restore_command present in recovery.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the comment describing why this behavior for high exit status from the command process was chosen, and the current code to implement it.

```
    /*
     * Remember, we rollforward UNTIL the restore fails so failure here is
     * just part of the process... that makes it difficult to determine
     * whether the restore failed because there isn't an archive to restore,
     * or because the administrator has specified the restore program
     * incorrectly.  We have to assume the former.
     *
     * However, if the failure was due to any sort of signal, it's best to
     * punt and abort recovery.  (If we "return false" here, upper levels will
     * assume that recovery is complete and start up the database!) It's
     * essential to abort on child SIGINT and SIGQUIT, because per spec
     * system() ignores SIGINT and SIGQUIT while waiting; if we see one of
     * those it's a good bet we should have gotten it too.
     *
     * On SIGTERM, assume we have received a fast shutdown request, and exit
     * cleanly. It's pure chance whether we receive the SIGTERM first, or the
     * child process. If we receive it first, the signal handler will call
     * proc_exit, otherwise we do it here. If we or the child process received
     * SIGTERM for any other reason than a fast shutdown request, postmaster
     * will perform an immediate shutdown when it sees us exiting
     * unexpectedly.
     *
     * Per the Single Unix Spec, shells report exit status > 128 when a called
     * command died on a signal.  Also, 126 and 127 are used to report
     * problems such as an unfindable command; treat those as fatal errors
     * too.
     */
    if (WIFSIGNALED(rc) && WTERMSIG(rc) == SIGTERM)
        proc_exit(1);

    signaled = WIFSIGNALED(rc) || WEXITSTATUS(rc) > 125;

    ereport(signaled ? FATAL : DEBUG2,
            (errmsg("could not restore file \"%s\" from archive: %s",
                    xlogfname, wait_result_to_str(rc))));
```